# ant/Jenkins: move doesn't support the "quiet" attribute

Tags: ant, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

My build script executes:

```
<move todir="gen" overwrite="true" quiet="true">
        <fileset dir="gen">
            <include name="**/BuildConfig.java.new"/>
        </fileset>
        <globmapper from="*.java.new" to="*.java"/>
</move>
```

I get the error:

```
move doesn't support the "quiet" attribute
```

I have ant 1.8.4 installed on my iMac. My ant plugin in Jenkins is 1.2. Jenkins ver. 1.505.
I have tried to change the PATH when starting Jenkins, so it includes my command line ant.
However it seems that Jenkins does not support ant 1.8.3? ant 1.8.3 is the version where the "move quiet" was added.

Any thoughts how I can solve this? Is it related to command line ant or plugin ant or my build script?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by:

1. In Jenkins setup, set a tool location for ant
   [image]
2. Now in my build job a new selection appeared: Ant Version
   [image]

My ant on my mac:

```
ant -v
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on May 22 2012
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're running Jenkins on your iMac, go to [http://yourjenkins/configure] and add an Ant installation that points to your Ant 1.8.4 directory.  Then, in the Ant build step of your Jenkins job configuration, specify that version of Ant and things should start working.

If your Jenkins server is on a different machine, repeat the instructions but install Ant 1.8.4 on the Jenkins server, or use the "Install automatically" option to install Ant on demand.

Comment: Im on my local mac. Did a grep -i ant in my jenkins home, no result. Do you mean I need to edit config.xml? Where can I point to my ant directory in jenkins config files? Updated question with picture.