# ant/Jenkins: move doesn't support the "quiet" attribute

Tags: jenkins, ant

My build script executes:

```
<move todir="gen" overwrite="true" quiet="true">
    <fileset dir="gen">
        <include name="**/BuildConfig.java.new"/>
    </fileset>
    <globmapper from="*.java.new" to="*.java"/>
</move>
```

I get the error:

```
move doesn't support the "quiet" attribute
```

I have ant 1.8.4 installed on my iMac. My ant plugin in Jenkins is 1.2. Jenkins ver. 1.505. I have tried to change the PATH when starting Jenkins, so it includes my command line ant. However it seems that Jenkins does not support ant 1.8.3? ant 1.8.3 is the version where the "move quiet" was added.

Any thoughts how I can solve this? Is it related to command line ant or plugin ant or my build script? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use verbose="false" instead of 'quiet'.

See [Move Ant Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/move.html).

Comment: My answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393890/ant-jenkins-move-doesnt-support-the-quiet-attribute